How to prevent repeated error messages for consecutive invalid inputs in Java?
I am working on a Java program that requires user input validation. The program asks the user to enter a number greater than 10, and if the input is invalid (e.g., non-numeric or a number ≤ 10), it displays an error message. However, when the user repeatedly enters invalid inputs, the program prints the same error message every time, which feels redundant.
Here’s my current code:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;

        System.out.println("Enter a number greater than 10:");

        while (true) {
            try {
                number = scanner.nextInt();
                if (number > 10) {
                    System.out.println("You entered: " + number);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 10.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                scanner.next(); // Clear the invalid input
            }
        }

        scanner.close();
    }
}

Issue:
Whenever the user keeps entering invalid inputs, the error message (e.g., “Invalid input. Please try again.”) is printed repeatedly. I would like to modify this behavior so that the error message is displayed only once for consecutive invalid inputs.
Question:
How can I adjust my code to avoid redundant error messages for consecutive invalid inputs? Are there better approaches or patterns in Java to simplify input validation in this context?

(A) By the way, don’t close a Scanner based on System.in. You close the underlying stream, which means no more user input is possible. (B) In future versions of Java we may be able to use an improved Console class instead of System.in/.out, and avoid such problems. Feature being previewed now in Java 23 and 24.

There are a couple of Exceptions that can be thrown by nextInt(), not only InputMismatchException (e.g. NoSuchElementException); even the other methods can throw many Exceptions (RuntimeException) - I recommend to catch only InputMismatchException according the posted message (can be misleading otherwise); I also prefer outputting the error message (which in this case also includes the [faulty] input)

Hello taf, if you don't print the message, how would the user know to re-enter a value?.

Flag
Use a flag to keep track of when you issue the “invalid input” message.
When you go to post the message, check your flag.

If the flag is lowered, then you know the message has not yet been delivered to the user. Deliver the message, and raise the flag.
If the flag is raised, then skip over your message.

In code below we use a boolean variable named issuedInvalidInputMessage as our flag.
    ➡️  boolean issuedInvalidInputMessage = false ;  // Flag is lowered, at start. 
        while (true) {
            try {
                number = scanner.nextInt();
                if (number > 10) {
                    System.out.println("You entered: " + number);
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 10.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
     ➡️         if ( ! issuedInvalidInputMessage ) {
     ➡️             issuedInvalidInputMessage = true ;  // Raise the flag. 
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Please try again.");
                }
                scanner.next(); // Clear the invalid input
            }
        }

